# How to show bar labels in legend in Chart.js 2.1.6?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm creating charts using Chart.js and I want to show the labels for the bars in the legend, **not** the title of the dataset (there is only one), please see the below image as an example:

[image: Example of desired legend]

My current legend just looks like this: [image: My current legend]

I have looked through the docs but to no avail, I found them very confusing actually.

Here is my current code:

```
var chart_0 = new Chart($('#cp_chart_0'), {
      type: 'bar'
    , data: {
          labels: ['Blue','Green','Yellow','Red','Purple','Orange']
        , datasets: [{
              label: 'Dataset 1'
            , borderWidth: 0
            , backgroundColor: ['#2C79C5','#7FA830','#7B57C3','#ED4D40','#EC802F','#1DC6D3']
            , data: ['12','2','5','0','9','1']
        }]
      }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to provide your data with multiple sets :

```
  data: {
      labels: ['total votes']
    , datasets: [{
          label: 'Blue'
        , backgroundColor: ['#2C79C5']
        , data: ['12']
    },{
          label: 'Green'
        , backgroundColor: ['#7FA830']
        , data: ['2']
    },
    ...
    ]
  }
```

But you can generate a custom labels using `generateLabels` - http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration

Or even customise the whole legend, including formatting, with `legendCallback` - http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration

Comment: That did it, thanks! I split into multiple sets then created my own legend with `chart_0.generateLegend()` so I have more control over it.

Answer (score 2):

In one of the most recent releases of Chart.js 2.1.x, they added back this functionality. So go get the latest release first. Then insert the code below.

It is located under the options and legend. Here is how you use it:

```
options: {
    legend: {
        position: 'right'
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks for the tip! I ended up going with Hugo's answer to split into multiple datasets and created my own legend with `chart_0.generateLegend()` so I have more control over it - but after splitting into multiple datasets this worked too.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses **Chart.js version 3**. You can pre-process your data using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code.

I use the `beforeInit` hook to create individual datasets for each defined label/value pair. Note that the `data` of these new datasets are defined in point format (for instance `[{ x: 1, y: 12 }]`):

```
beforeInit: chart => {
  let dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[0];
  chart.config.data.datasets = chart.config.data.labels.map((l, i) => ({
    label: l,
    data: [{ x: i + 1, y: dataset.data[i] }],
    backgroundColor: dataset.backgroundColor[i],
    categoryPercentage: 1
  }));
  chart.config.data.labels = undefined;
}
```

Further you need to define a second x-axis that will contain the labels.

```
x1: {
  offset: true,
  gridLines: {
    display: false
  }
}
```

The `labels` on `x1` need to be collected and defined programmatically each time the `hidden` state of a `dataset` changes. This can be done in the `beforeLayout` hook.

```
beforeLayout: chart => chart.options.scales.x1.labels = chart.config.data.datasets.filter((ds, i) => !chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden).map(ds => ds.label)
```

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    beforeInit: chart => {      
      let dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[0];
      chart.config.data.datasets = chart.config.data.labels.map((l, i) => ({
        label: l,
        data: [{ x: i + 1, y: dataset.data[i] }],
        backgroundColor: dataset.backgroundColor[i],
        categoryPercentage: 1
      }));
      chart.config.data.labels = undefined;
    },
    beforeLayout: chart => chart.options.scales.x1.labels = chart.config.data.datasets.filter((ds, i) => !chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden).map(ds => ds.label)
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      data: ['12', '2', '5', '0', '9', '1'],
      backgroundColor: ['#2C79C5', '#7FA830', '#FFF200', '#ED4D40', '#800080', '#EC802F']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      intersect: true,
      mode: 'nearest'
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'right'
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title: () => undefined
        }
      }
    },   
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      x: {
        display: false
      },
      x1: {
        offset: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="120"></canvas>
```