# Why the labels under chart are not corresponding with labels in legend in Chart.js for bar chart?

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js, bar-chart, legend

I would like to make a chart with labels on `xAxes` and the same labels in the legend. I was trying different solutions, but the best I got is the snippet below. I don't understand, why all bars are connected with my first label. Could you please help me to fix it?

I found a solution with would be almost perfect [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44831779/13884596), but unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected: after clicking on the label in legend all charts are hiding, not only one corresponding to the label I clicked.

```js
 var canvas2 = document.getElementById("wykres_kategorie");
    var ctxD2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxD2, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [
            'a','b','c'
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
              label: 'a',
              data: [   60  ],
              backgroundColor: [ 'red' ],
            },
        {
              label: 'b',
              data: [   80  ],
              backgroundColor: [ 'blue' ],
            },
        {
              label: 'c',
              data: [   50  ],
              backgroundColor: [ 'yellow' ],
            },
        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom'
      },
        responsive: true,
        scales: { xAxes: [{ 
                ticks: {
            autoSkip: false
        } }],
        yAxes:[{ ticks: {beginAtZero: true}}]}
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.20.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<canvas class='col-12 mx-auto' id="wykres_kategorie"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.labels` defines the ticks for a category axis. Following your configuration, the chart is expecting to have 3 data items for dataset, (first at tick 'a', second at tick 'b', third at tick 'c').
Instead, the `dataset.label` are used in the legend.

In your config, all datasets have got only 1 value and all values are related to the first `data.labels`, 'a'.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation I could better understand the problem and I found a nice solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515731/chart-js-manipulate-each-bar-in-chart-with-different-labels).