# Chartjs Legend for each bar

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to create a horizontal bar chart where both the data and labels are random. I also want to incorporate a legend for each bar, similar to a donut chart. The goal is to enable removal of a specific item by selecting its corresponding legend text.
I'm considering the option of creating multiple datasets, but I'm unsure if that is the best approach.
Im using Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js

Im expecting that i could create legend for each bar
Please suggest some good ideas without multiple datasets as well

Below code i was trying for creating new datasets based on labels and values:

```
const newDatasets = labels.map((label, index) => ({
  label: label,
  data: values[index],
}));
```

Here is my actual code:

```
const labels = category;
const values = count;

const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{

        data: values,
        backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(labels, reportColor[0]),
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 19,
        borderSkipped: false,
        barPercentage: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 0.1
    }]
    
};

const config = {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        font: {
            weight: 'bold'
        },
    },
},  
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        indexAxis: 'y',
        legend: { display: false },
        tooltips: {
            cornerRadius: 10
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                barThickness: 6,
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: yAxisLabel,
                    fontSize: 20
                },
                ticks: {
                    /*beginAtZero: true,*/
                    userCallback: function(label, index, labels) {
                        if (Math.trunc(label) === label) {
                            return label;
                        }
                    }
                },
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                barPercentage: 1.0,
                barThickness: 20,
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: xAxisLabel,
                    fontSize: 20
                },
            }]
        },
    },
};


horizontalBarChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById("horizontalBarChart"),
    config
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfHgT.png)

[Bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/676pf.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633397/2358409

Comment: @uminder I tried this solution but im unable to add yAxis label because they are hiding yAxis, I tried to add label but it is showing between Bars and Axis which is not good, Do you have any other solution

Comment: @uminder I have attached image in above question named Bar Image where you can have a look how its showing YAxisLabel between label and bar

Comment: @uminder How to handle AfterInit in plugins for multiple datasets?
How chart.data.labels.map will work with multiple dataset?

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand, you want to make a `Horizontal bar chart with random value` of each bar.

Here I've made something you want with the value of each bar inside the bar.

as you have used `Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js` is not working sometime so suggest you to use `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js` and for `datatabels plugin` use `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0`

```
// Setup
      var data = {
        labels: ['Playing', 'Not Playing'], // This is the label of the chart's Axis
        datasets: [ // datasets consists data of each label
          {
            label: 'Yes',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(78, 136, 250, 1)',
            data: [(Math.random()  95 + 5).toFixed(2), (Math.random()  95 + 5).toFixed(2)], // for random value
            borderRadius: 14,
            barPercentage: 0.9, // Adjust this value to change the width of bars (its value is from 0 to 1)
            
            // Below datalabels are to show the values of the bars at the top-bottom wherever we wants
            datalabels: {
              color: 'white', // color of the data labels
            }
          },
          {
            label: 'No',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(241, 156, 23, 1)',
            data: [(Math.random()  95 + 5).toFixed(2), (Math.random()  95 + 5).toFixed(2)], // for random value
            borderRadius: 14,
            barPercentage: 0.9, // Adjust this value to change the width of bars (its value is from 0 to 1)
            
            // Below datalabels are to show the values of the bars at the top-bottom wherever we wants
            datalabels: {
              color: 'royalblue', // color of the data labels
            }
          },
        ]
      };
  
      // Configuration
      var options = {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: { // legends are the labels of the graph
            position: 'top', // using position parameter we can adjust position of the legend in the chart area (Vertical)
            align: 'end', // align the legend at the end of the chart (Horizontal)
            labels: {
              boxWidth: 15,
              boxHeight: 6,
              useBorderRadius: true,
              borderRadius: 3,
              color: '#02d0d0',
              font: { 
                size: 16,
              },
              padding: 30, // spacing between the legend lables in px
            },
            onHover: function(event, legendItem) {
              document.getElementById('myChart').style.cursor = 'pointer'; // to show the cursor on hover of the legend
            },
          },
          tooltips: {
            // enabled: true,
            mode: "index",
            intersect: false,
          },

          // To Customise the data labels
          datalabels: {
            formatter: (value) => {
              return value + '%';
            },
            font: { 
              weight: 'bold',
            }
          },              
        },

        layout: {
          padding: 20,
        },

        scales: {
          y: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              stepSize: 25,
            },
            scaleLabel: { 
              display: false,
              labelString: 'Percentage',
            },
          },
        },
      };
  
      // Create chart
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'); // ctx is nothing but the small for of the word "ConTeXt" and we can use any thing as this is a name of the variable.
      
      // Config
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data, // gets the data from the var data
        options: options,
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels], // add this as it activates the datalabel plugin
      });
```

Please refer below JSFiddle link for the demo.
[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/95dhw6zb/)

Hope this is helpful to you.

Thanks.

Comment: You are having 2 datasets but im having only 1 dataset and i want legend for each bar
in your example its not like that

Comment: Replace below code in `setup` part of the chart as you want only one dataset and legend of each bar:
        var labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
        var dataVal = labels.map(() => (Math.random() * 95 + 5).toFixed(2)); // for random value
        var data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Course Completion',
                backgroundColor: ['#2d70ff', '#f19c17'],
                data: dataVal,
                borderRadius: 7,
                datalabels: { color:'white' },
            }]
        };